# Proof: CFG has balanced parentheses

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, induction

I'm currently enrolled to a CS course about programming languages and we learned about structural induction. In a question from our home assignments we need to proof that the following CFG has balanced parentheses:

[image]

My initial solution used simple induction and following the derivation rules of the CFG but the TA told us we need a stronger induction assumption that R has one more left parentheses than right parentheses.
Can someone give me general direction to follow?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the axiom is $E2$. By substituting $R$ in $E2$ you get the equivalent grammar:
$$
E2 \to \varepsilon \mid \text{id} \mid () \mid  (E2)
$$

You can show by induction on the number $i$ of productions used that every sentential form of the above grammar has balanced parentheses.

The base case is $i=0$ and is trivial since $E2$ has no parentheses.
For the inductive step notice that the only possible production replaces a single occurrence $E2$ with a sequence of symbols that has balanced parentheses. Therefore the resulting sentential form also has balanced parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

We perform the induction on derivation steps. Let's say that our derivation of some sentence in $L(E2)$ is composed of $k$ steps, the first step is denoted as $V \xrightarrow{k} \alpha$, the second step (if $k >= 2$) will be $ \alpha \xrightarrow{k-1} \beta$, and so on. I'll be assuming that the starting symbol is $E2$

It's trivial that $E2 \xrightarrow{1} id | \epsilon $ lead to balanced parentheses. Also $E2 \xrightarrow{2} (R \xrightarrow{1} () $ is well balanced

So now we perform the inductive step for $k > 2$, with induction hypothesis that $E2 \xrightarrow{h} \cdots \xrightarrow{1} \alpha$ has well balanced parentheses for $h < k $. We must  have the derivation steps $E2 \xrightarrow{k} (R \xrightarrow{k-1} (E2) \xrightarrow{k-2} \cdots \xrightarrow{1} (\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ will have balanced parantheses by induction hypothesis